# Updating SVN in OSX command line project

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, svn, command-line

I need to run and SVN commit using Objective C
The code to run SVN command is like this using an ***command line application***

```
NSString *command = @"svn add folder; svn commit -m \"Test Add\""
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c",command, nil];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
[task setArguments:arguments];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
[task launch];
NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Output %@",output);
```

but I am getting this error

```
svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at ...
You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see
  http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change
```

I tried updating the command line tools but didnt work

On initial stages I tried SVN commit using terminal but it also showed the same error so based on this [link](http://www.jarysta.com/2014/10/16/updating-to-svn-1-8-for-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/) I have updated the SVN using terminal too but it still shows the error on running the code

I also updated **/bin/sh** with new SVN but doest work (Also tried with **/bin/bash**)

Any suggestion to avoid this error and commit it to repository ??

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294420/svn-e155021-this-client-is-too-old-to-work-with-the-working-copy-at-xxx-forma

Comment: Already went through that link, also it has no accepted answer

Comment: You still have an old version of the svn binaries hanging around on your system. You need to find them and upgrade them. Why aren't you using the C bindings/libraries directly? Wouldn't that be better than calling an external program?

Comment: when I check the version of svn i get as 1.8.9 and works with terminal but when i run it through Command line app it gives me that error!!!  And what do you mean by using the C bindings/libraries directly ? Can you give a reference or some code reference ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution

I used the ***which svn*** command to find where the svn was installed
now, while running the command from run button in Xcode it was giving the location as **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn**

but the terminal was using the location
**/usr/local/bin/svn**

So under Xcode goto Products folder and copy the **Application Name.app** file and paste it to desktop and double click to run it and now it will work fine

But if you need a work around this is what I did

***Do it at your own risk***

1. Goto /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ and copy all files starting with svn title and keep it as backup.(Please remember the files that you copy)
2. Goto /usr/local/bin/svn and copy and replace svn files from here to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
3. Now run it and you will not get any version error

Cheers !!! :)